# want to restart browser and go to script in url

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser

Here is my code:

`var appStartup = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/toolkit/app-startup;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIAppStartup);
appStartup.quit(appStartup.eForceQuit | appStartup.eRestart);`

I tried to set url for my script or any other url in startpage, but after restart browser open recent tabs.

I tried to start firefox with params

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -no-remote -p "profilename" -imacros://run/?m=scriptname.js`

Comment: Anything you try with programming code to restart a user's browser will fail.  Whatever you could do for good reasons, others should not be able to do for bad reasons.

Comment: May be sombody give me advice...

Comment: I have two scripts, which must running 24/7 in different windows. But Firefox devours all my RAM after few hours of work. I want to add restarting browser and start my script again.
I cant use .bat file, which will look for firefox.exe in task manager and run ff if it's closed. Because two windows will have same names.